# RESTSharp empty body on ExecuteAsyncPost versus ExecutePost

Tags: c#, rest, restsharp

I'm using RestSharp to build a Rest access to my MVC entry points (actually so I can use them from monotouch, but right now I'm testing on Windows 7, vs2010, .net 4, RestSharp 104.1)

if I create a request and call

```
client.ExecuteAsPost<Model.Client>( request );
```

it works, I can see in fiddler the raw packet

```
POST http://localhost.:49165/Services/Client/ClientAdminService/FindClient HTTP/1.1 
Timestamp: Monday, March 18, 2013 1:56:02 AM 
X-PS-Authentication: YADAYADA:<deleted for brevity>== 
Accept: application/xml 
User-Agent: RestSharp 104.1.0.0 
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8 
Host: localhost.:49165 
Content-Length: 256 
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate 
Connection: Keep-Alive


<Client xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/PSRMWebService.Model.Version1" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><ID>0</ID><MailingAddress i:nil="true"/><Mask>Name</Mask><Name>Rykercom</Name><PhysicalAddress i:nil="true"/></Client>
```

as you can see at the end is the serialized data blob I need to send to the server (of type Model.Client) this is added to the request using

```
Request.AddParameter("application/xml; charset=utf-8", DataPacket, RestSharp.ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

where DataPacket is the serialized blob created using a DataContractSerializer

Now if I change the code to call

```
Client.ExecuteAsyncPost<Model.Client>(Request, (response, handle) => { OnFindClientAsyncComplete(response, handle, Callback ); }, "POST");
```

Using Fiddler I get quite a different packet with no Body, no content type, and therefore a failed response from the server.

```
POST http://localhost.:49165/Services/Client/ClientAdminService/FindClient HTTP/1.1
Timestamp: Monday, March 18, 2013 2:35:08 AM
X-PS-Authentication: YADAYADA:<deleted for bevity>==
Accept: application/xml
User-Agent: RestSharp 104.1.0.0
Host: localhost.:49165
Content-Length: 0
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

the X-PS-Authentication is just a custom auth string. Anyone any ideas why the async call is leaving me with an empty message body ?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is clone the current github repository for rest sharp and build it yourself. It appears the fix for executeasync is already in the tree.

Any chance who ever own the Nuget package can update it to the lastest sources ?

Thanks